# swift: translation animation on rotated view

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, rotation, translation

I have a `UIImageView`that is upside down. Then I want to apply a translation animation to this view. The problem is when the view is rotated, The view doesn't appear on screen, but when I remove the line that aplies the rotation before the animation, everything works fine. I don't understand why would the view not even show up.

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
UIView.animateWithDuration(rocketAnimationDuration, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations:
    {
        rocket.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(rocket.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, translationY))
    }, completion: nil)
```

If I remove the first view, the view shows up and is animated.
If I place the first line into the brackets, the views shows up and is animated (with the rotation).

Any idea why does this happen? Thanks

EDIT: I managed to make it work without applying a rotation on the `UIImageView` by adding a mirror effect on the `UIImage`. But I'd like to understand why does this problem happen when a rotation has been applied before...

Comment: What is your view hierarchy?

Comment: @ArunAmmannaya: The UIImageView is in a UIView that is itself in the VC's view

Comment: Same code worked for me with hierarchy you mentioned. What is the value of translationY in your case?

Comment: It is the height of the `UIImageView`'s parent. You managed to have a flipped image moving ?

Comment: Yes. Works perfectly for me.